# VB6 Byte array in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, vb6

I have some image comparison DLL, and documentation for VB6, but I want to use it in ASP.NET/VB.NET

In documentation is stated following:

> iDLLoadImage
>
> Description : Load the captured image (in raw format), preparing for
>   face detection.
>
> Declaration : iDLLoadImage (pByte As Byte, iWidth As Long, iHeight As
>   Long,  iColor As Long)
>
> Parameters : pByte    : byte array which stored the (raw) captured image
>   (in) iWidth   : for setting raw image width (in) iHeight  : for setting
>   raw image height (in) iColor  : 1 for Gray image, 3 for RGB image (in)
>
> Return Values : 0 : Successful
>   -1    : This library is not enabled.
>   -2    : pByte is NULL.
>   -3    : Failed to initialize internal parameters

But, when I try to pass it `byte array` in VB.NET it says it expects `byte`.

Is there any solution for this?

(And here's screenshot) https://i.stack.imgur.com/giORJ.png

Thanks.

Comment: Try to pass image(0).

Comment: @Dabblernl VB.NET will still pass single byte.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the receiving code perhaps just likes to know the position in memory of the first element of the array. Hence the ByRef keyword in its declaration. Try to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

1. A Dabblernl said, try using image(0) as a parameter. Since it is byref, it may pass the memory location and from there process the entire array.
2. You may be able to declare the function as an alias, and change the first parameter to `pByte As Byte()`.